# ASP.Net Web App does everything but Update Database (C# MS SQL)

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net

I have created an ASP.Net website using C# and MS SQL Server.
I have been able to insert data into my database, load it back, and delete it; but I have failed to be able to update my database.

My update command is: (I have tried with and without quotes around @badge.)

```
SqlCommand updateDB = new SqlCommand("UPDATE UserRequest  SET ur_winIT =@winIT, ur_sigWinIT=@sigWinIT,ur_IGTIT = @IGTIT, " + " ur_sigIGTIT = @sigIGTIT" + "WHERE ur_badgeNum ='@badge'", con);
    try
    {
        con.Open();
        updateDB.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
    catch
    {
        MessageBack2.Text = "Connection to Database Failed.  Could not Update, please try again.";
    }
    finally
    {
        con.Close();
    }
```

Comment: I guess by 'have not been able to update' you mean you cannot observe any change to the data? I suggest you use SQL Profiler to observe the update to the database.

Comment: I have observed it in the SQL Profiler, and it shows the updated values being passed, but when I query the table, nothing has actually changed.

Comment: Put a debugger at updatedb.executenonquery() and get the generated sql query and execute it directly on database then you'll find the error.

Comment: Few things to try:
Are you sure you connected to same database, sometimea my connection in SQL management studio points to different db than where my code.
Could you check if there is any trigger reverting the update.

Looks like It surely is updating else you could see some errors.

Comment: I am sure it is the same database because I can add new tables, and delete them as well.  I always go back and double check in SQL Server Management Studio and query what is currently stored.

Comment: I don't see you setting `@badge` anywhere in your code. it's possible your UPDATE doesn't have a matching record or it's not updating the record you expect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to get it to update! I had to add [] around each database item.

`SqlCommand updateDB = new SqlCommand("UPDATE UserRequest  SET [ur_winIT]=@winIT, [ur_sigWinIT]=@sigWinIT WHERE [ur_badgeNum] = @badge", con);`

Thanks for all your help!